# Yii как связать несколько таблиц через зависимость

Tags: yii

Вот стандартная связь будет такой

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'page' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'book', 'book_id'),           
    );
}
```

а вот можно ли сделать более глубокую зависимость как в таком примере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы по id page узнать id автора?

Comment: Как насчет промежуточной таблицы?

Comment: а смысл плодить сущности?

Comment: Чуть большее количество таблиц - неплохая цена за более простые и понятные запросы. Смысл городить огород в коде?